# Select query with order by in criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'd like to create a criteria query from this SQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM `Product` p
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Sale` WHERE `product_id` = p.id) DESC
```

I cannot find a way to do it with the sub query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Order By` is only applicable for a column which is present in the `select` part.

So basically something like this will work:

```
SELECT Group, COUNT(*) as total
FROM table
GROUP BY Group
ORDER BY total DESC
```

So for your case, you can do something like following:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Sale` WHERE `product_id` = p.id) as total FROM `Product` p
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Note: This is completely untested.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea how to create a criteria query with this SQL query?

Comment: see if these docs help : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/

Answer (score 1):

Try an implicit join:

```
select *
from (
    select 
         p.*, 
         (select count(*) from sale s where s.product_id = p.id) as cnt 
    from product p
)a 
order by cnt desc
```